# Get IP addresses of Hyper-V Linux machines

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012, and in the Hyper-v I have CentOS 6/7 vm.
I doing the following command:

```
Get-vm -name "x" | select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters
```

Output:

```
Name            IsManagementOs VMName SwitchName     MacAddress Status                         IPAddresses

----            -------------- ------ ----------     ---------- ------                         -----------

Network Adapter False          "x"    InternalSwitch Mac        {Degraded, protocolversion} {}
```

Why is `IPAddresses` empty?

I tried `(command).ipaddresses` and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install Linux Integration Services to the virtual machine (*[Linux Integration Services 4.1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2016/03/21/linux-integration-services-4-1/)*):

1. Download the package from *[Linux Integration Services Version 4.1 for Hyper-V](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51612)* to the guest server (Linux) and unpack it. There is also an ISO image available that you can mount with Hyper-V Manager if you have no way of transferring the package to the guest host.
2. Find your distribution under the unpacked directory (e.g. `CentOS72`).
3. Run `install.sh` as root.
4. Reboot the guest OS.

For CentOS 7 it also required to disable NetworkManager. That (and other hints) is told in *[Supported CentOS and Red Hat Enterprise Linux virtual machines on Hyper-V](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/supported-centos-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v)* (Notes 2 for NetworkManager)

Run: `systemctl disable NetworkManager` and reboot

Now the Hyper-V Manager should show you the IP address of the VM and [`Get-VM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/get-vm?view=win10-ps) should also work.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

You're not alone here, I have this issue too. Make sure that you're **running PowerShell as admin**, or you wouldn't get any IP addresses at all. And even if it run as admin, I still can get IP address only for one VM out of 30 on my host.

Answer (score 0):

I could not solve this issue using PowerShell tools, but there is a workaround:

You can get the MAC address of your VM with `Get-VMNetworkAdapter`. From the Hyper-V host, ping the IP address range you know you VM can get (from DHCP I suppose), and test the ARP table for the MAC address.